# Do Camel routes not run on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, apache-camel, noclassdeffounderror

I should preface this by saying that I'm using Camel 2.10.3 and GAE SDK 1.7.1.

I just packaged the following code into my `CamelServlet`, and deployed the WAR to my local dev app server instance for GAE:

```
public class CamelServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        RouteBuilder routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start").process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                        logger.warning("I am inside a Camel route!");
                    }
                }).to("direct:end");
            }
        };

        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

        try {
            camelContext.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
            camelContext.start();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            camelContext.stop();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            logger.warning("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8888/camel` (which is where I have the `CamelServlet` mapped), I get a stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent.findOrCreateMBeanServer(DefaultManagementAgent.java:364)
    at org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent.createMBeanServer(DefaultManagementAgent.java:348)
    at org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent.doStart(DefaultManagementAgent.java:253)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementStrategy.start(DefaultManagementStrategy.java:209)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.management.ManagementStrategyFactory.create(ManagementStrategyFactory.java:40)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.createManagementStrategy(DefaultCamelContext.java:2490)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getManagementStrategy(DefaultCamelContext.java:2310)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1499)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1444)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1412)
    at com.myapp.server.servlets.CamelServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

*Restricted*?!?! Is a Camel route/bus not supposed to run on GAE?!? Camel has a GAE component (Camel-GAE), which I *thought* was a form of validation that you can in fact run Camel on GAE. But now I'm worried that it's just for consuming from a GAE endpoint, and not actually meant to be ran on GAE...

So either it's not possible to run/start a Camel route on GAE, or there's a special way I need to configure the route objects (`DefaultCamelContext`, etc.) to not violate GAE restricted classes. Or, something entirely different is happening. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

**Update**

After diabling JMX via `camelContext.disableJMX();` I get a new (very similar) exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.InitialContext is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry.createContext(JndiRegistry.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry.getContext(JndiRegistry.java:92)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry.lookup(JndiRegistry.java:65)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry.lookup(JndiRegistry.java:47)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookup(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1557)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1444)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1412)
    at com.myapp.server.servlets.CamelServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off JMX and you should be fine.

```
// spring xml
<camel:camelContext id="camelContext">
   <!-- JMX is not supported in GAE -->
   <camel:jmxAgent id="agent" disabled="true"/>
   ...

// or in your case, java DSL
CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(new SimpleRegistry());
camelContext.disableJMX();
```

**Updated:**
   And if you are using a DefaultCamelContext you might want to avoid using the default JNDI registry. Instead create a SimpleRegistry when creating the context (See code above). A spring config camel context does not have this as default, since it uses the spring registry.

Proof that is works:
http://camelcloud.appspot.com/

Comment: Thanks @Petter (+1) - but after disabling JMX I get a different (similar) error in `InitialContext`. I looked for a `disableInitialContext()` method but don't see one. Please see my update for the full stack trace. And thanks again!

Comment: Nevermind - answered my own question. GAE doesn't allow JNDI either, and `DefaultCamelContext` uses JNDI by default as a bean registry. So I just create the context with a `SimpleRegistry` like so and all is well: `CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(new SimpleRegistry());`. Thanks again!